# 2008 SSRS Chart Secondary Axis Data Value not being displayed

Tags: reporting-services

I use 2008 SSRS and am new to SSRS.  I am trying to create a bar chart that has a line chart as the secondary axis.  Within the Chart Data window, under **Value**s, I have 'loan_count' as the primary axis and 'offer_percent' as the secondary axis.  Under **Category Groups** I have the column 'month'.  Under **Series Groups**, I have the column 'metrics'.  For the 'metrics' column (Series Groups), I created a filter: [metrics] in Ending Inventory, Inventory with Offer (includes 2 values).

Let's look at the secondary axis under Values.  The column used is 'offer_percent'.  This is the column that does not show up in the report.  In my attempt to fix this problem, under its Series Properties I have an expression: `=IsNothing(Fields!offer_percent.Value) <> true = true`.  I am using this 'not null' expression because 'offer_percent' is present (not null) only when `'metrics' = 'offer_per_inventory'`.  With this expression, the report still doesn't show the values of offer_percent.

I hope I am clear with my issues.  Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Edit : format code

Comment: I dont understand the meaning of your 2nd para. Which property are you trying to set, and why?

Comment: Anyway I would review the filter - these are very tricky and best avoided if possible. Try running without it to isolate the problem.